# Why will Jest run code that has an incorrect import statement?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

This issue I am having is that I had a mistake in a javascript program; the import line did not include the `.js` extension.

The understandably meant that the program failed to with node as `./import` does not exist (`./import.js` does). The error I reflected this `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module .../export' imported from ...`.

However, when testing with `jest`, it works 'correctly' (as if the file extension was included). Does anyone know why this code is 'correct' for jest even though the file it is trying to import from does not really exist?

I have setup a very small repo [here](https://github.com/jmsapt/weird-jest-behaviour) that replicates this issue (with the same configs). Hopefully this provides all full context regarding my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run code in Jest, you are using Jest's import system. This is more advanced than the default JavaScript import system. It can do things like "guessing" extensions.

Therefore the code likely *is* running correctly via Jest.

Look in `jest.config.js`, does it list which extensions to try? E.g. `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts`? If so, that is your answer.

Comment: Thank you! 

Just for reference (if someone else has the same issue), the array of extensions are stored in `config.moduleFileExtensions` (see [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/configuration#modulefileextensions-arraystring))